# how to make a 9*9 grid view in Objective C under Xcode 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

i have searched Xcode controls but doesn't found anything that makes a GridView like the one in the lecture below so, how to make a one like that? thanks [image: A 9*9 gridView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Stephen pointed out, there's AQGridView, but here are a few others I've looked at, each offering some different functionality based on what you're looking for: [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView), [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView), [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such component built in to iOS. So you'll either need to write your own or look for an open source version. I'm aware of [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView); I'm sure there are others.

Comment: is there's a demo images(ScreenShot) of these AQGridView?

Comment: Don't think so. You can probably get the demo app up and running in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6 has a UICollectionView that might work

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html