# IOS UIView Auto scroll grid images

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, animation, mobile

I am looking create a basic iphone app which can automatically scroll down a list of grid images, How can I do this?

I have attached an example grid image which I would like to be able to scroll automatically:

http://0.tqn.com/d/ipod/1/0/b/3/-/-/iphone_gallery_6.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Well for this you have a number of options. Either you can create your own gridview using the following links :-

[how to design and create a GridView using UIScrollView or UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140710/how-to-design-and-create-a-gridview-using-uiscrollview-or-uitableview)
[how to make a 9*9 grid view in Objective C under Xcode 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770132/how-to-make-a-99-grid-view-in-objective-c-under-xcode-4-3)

http://ios-funda.blogspot.in/2012/12/creating-grid-view-in-ios.html
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Or if you want to access some controls you can go through :-

https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView

https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysGridView

https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionView if you don't know how to use the UICollectionView i can paste my code here

[Creating UICollectionView programmatically](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)